# Creating a grid with a specific order

Tags: matlab, grid

I want to create a two column 20x20 grid (x,y) with 0.2 resolution on specific orders. First I know how to create the grid by fixing y every time and populating x as follows:

```
 [y, x] = meshgrid(0:0.2:20);
 grid = [x(:) y(:)];
```

The order I want my grid to be in is the following:

-Starting at y=0 and x=0 , fix y and increase x by 2 until the end of that x line is reached.

-Increase y by 2 and repeat the above.

-After reaching the end of the grid, (20,20), start again at y=0 but x=0.2 and increase y by 2 ever time you reach the end of x.

-After filling all these line, start the above at y=0.2 and x=0

The points will be in this order

> (0,0) (2,0) (4,0)...(20,0),(0,2) (2,2) (4,2)...(20,2),...(0,20) (2,20)
>   (4,20)...(20,20), (0.2,0) (2.2,0) (4.2,0)...(18.2,0),(0.2,2) (2.2,2)
>   (4.2,2)...(18.2,2),...(0.2,20) (2.2,20) (4.2,20)...(18.2,20)....
>   (0,0.2) (2,0.2) (4,0.2)...(20,0.2),(0,2.2) (2,2.2)
>   (4,2.2)...(20,2.2),...

I know it's hard to explain but this code does the trick

```
  grid = [];
   for j = 0:0.2:1.8
   for i = 0:0.2:1.8
      for v = j:2:20
         for u = i:2:20
             x = [u v];
             spot = [grid;x];
         end
      end
   end
end
```

Also I can do the same but starting at (20,20) and go from right to left

```
spot=[];
for j = 20:-0.2:18.2
   for i = 20:-0.2:18.2
      for v = j:-2:0
         for u = i:-2:0
             x = [v u];
             spot = [spot;x];
         end
      end
   end
end
```

My first question is, is there a more efficient way to write this code?

The second question is, I want to divide this grid into two parts. Part 1 starts at (0,0) and go right to left (as the first code above), and stops at (10,10). Part 2 starts at (20,20), and go left to right (the second code), and stops at (10,10).

The only way I'm able to do it now is create the above grids and then manually deleting unwanted rows

Comment: I cannot get the second the second question.

Answer (score 0):

This solution creates the same grid but order of rows is different than your grid:

```
z = (0:.2:1.8) + (0:2:20).';
[x y] = ndgrid(z(z<=20));
grid2 = [x(:) y(:)];
```

To test equality of your grid with the current grid:

```
isequal(sortrows(grid2),sortrows(grid))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution

```
x=0:2:20;
y = .2:2:18.2;
[X Y] = meshgrid(x);

%first sequence
seq1 = cat(3,Y ,X);
res1 = reshape(seq1, [],2);

%second sequence
[X2 Y2] = meshgrid(x,y);
seq2 = cat(3,Y2,X2);
res2 = reshape(seq2, [],2);

%third sequence
[X3 Y3] = meshgrid(y, x);  %or use the meshgrid from the previous step
seq3 = cat(3,Y3,X3);
res3 = reshape(seq3, [],2);

%Result
result = [res1;res2;res3];
```

And the order seems to be in agreement with what was given in the question.

For the second question, if the order is fixed as is implied in the question, then (10,10) will be the 61st element of the 2D array. Therefore:

```
result(1:61);  %will give array values starting from the beginning up to (10,10)
```

The elements from (10,10) to the end of the array can be computed in a similar fashion.